# Laptop wifi not working with one particular router

Tags: router, website, window

There is a laptop that has a connecting problem to the internet with one particular router. Actually I'm not sure that the problem is with the router or not! I was able to load google.com and get search results, images, etc.

However, no other website will load up. The laptop works just fine when connected to other routers. Other computers work just fine with this router.

Any ideas? I know that I did not provide too much to go on so please ask any questions that you might have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be problems on both sides

1. Did you reset to factory setting and reconfigure the router?
2. Did you delete the network profile on your laptop and reconnect?
3. Are you using any proxies?

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure of the following:

1. The firmware on the router is up to date.
2. The drivers on the laptop are up to date.

The first is generally a simple check with the manufacturer of the router.  The second can be more complicated in the Windows world (you don't mention the OS) as you may need to check with the manufacturer of the laptop, with the manufacturer of the wireless adapter, and/or the manufacturer of the chipset in the adapter.

There can also be settings on the router that will create problems with certain client devices, but I would start with the above.